# How to make a stack that contains structs?

Tags: c, struct, stack

So for a few days now Im killing myself on how to make a stack that contains structs. In the beginning I thought that would be easy but it turned out it isn't (for me).

So the problem goes like this: The user gives the size of the stack and then I must initialize the stack, then goes push, pop and display. My concern now is how to initialize it. I know I have to do it with malloc but I don't know how.

Note: The structs that are supposed to be in stack are "stud" and "prof".

Heres the stack I made:

```
struct MyStack
{
    int head;
    void **stack;
    int size;
};
typedef struct MyStack STACK;
struct stud
{
     char flag;
     char fname[50];
     int semester;
};
struct prof
{
     char flag;
     char fname[50];
     char course[30];
};
int main()
{
    int size,sel;
    size=GiveSize();
    STACK NewStack;
    NewStack.size = size;
}
```

Now what? Is it:

NewStack.stack = (struct *("prof" or "stud"?)) malloc(size*sizeof(struct ("prof" or "stud"?)

How can I know what type the stack is?

Thanks Chnossos!! You really helped me :)

Answer (score 1):

Simply do something like that ...

```
void print_stack (STACK * stack)
{
    struct stud * s;
    s = stack->stack[0];
    printf("Student (%c) %s is in semester %d.\n", s->flag, s->fname, s->semester);
}

int main()
{
    struct stud student = { 's', "toto", 1 };
    int size, sel;

    size = GetSize();
    STACK NewStack;

    NewStack.size = size;
    NewStack.stack = malloc((size + 1) * sizeof(void *));
    NewStack.stack[size] = NULL;

    NewStack.stack[0] = &student;

    print_stack(&NewStack);

    return 0;
}
```

... which successfully prints `Student (s) toto is in semester 1.`.

---

To print the whole stack :

```
#define STUDENT_FLAG    's'
#define PROF_FLAG       'p'

void print_student (struct stud *s)
{
    printf("Student (%c) %s is in semester %d.\n", s->flag, s->fname, s->semester);
}

void print_prof (struct prof *p)
{
    printf("Prof (%c) %s is in course %d.\n", p->flag, p->fname, p->course);
}

void print_full_stack (STACK * stack)
{
    char flag;
    int i;

    for (i = 0 ; i < stack->size ; ++i)
    {
        flag = *(char *)(stack->stack[i]);
        if (flag == STUDENT_FLAG)
            print_student(stack->stack[i]);
        else if (flag == PROF_FLAG)
            print_prof(stack->stack[i]);
    }
}
```

**Note that this will only work if the `flag` variable is declared first in every structure stored in the stack.**

Comment: why is it "size+1" instead of just "size"?

Comment: That way you can NULL-terminate the array. It is not a requirement since you store the size as well, it's just one of my reflexes.

Comment: if I wanted to show all the structs in the stack using for(..) how would it look like inside a function? ex. PrintFullStack()

Comment: is stack[0]=NULL? thats why you start with ++i?

Comment: In a for-loop, `++i` or `i++` is only a matter of personal style and both produce the same result.

Comment: instead of creating a flag in the function can't I simply make:      if (stack->stack[i].flag == STUDENT_FLAG)?

Comment: The type of `stack->stack[i]` is `void *`, so the answer is no.

Comment: i noticed something strange. If i put this line: struct stud student = { 's', "toto", 1 };... under this line: STACK NewStack; the program crashes..why is that?

Comment: Nothing happens if I do this too. Without more context, I can't tell. Consider closing this question if a suitable answer has been provided, and reopen one with your new problem.

Answer (score -3):

you can simply use template stack object by including stack header

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stack>

using namespace std;

struct stud
{
     char flag;
     char fname[50];
     int semester;
}d;
int main()
{
    stack<stud> s;
    stud d;
    d.flag='a';
    strcpy(d.fname,"saurah");
    d.semester=4;
    s.push(d);
    stud f=s.top();
    s.pop();
    cout<<f.fname;
    return 0;
    }
```